# Can't get SingleValueExtendedProperties from Outlook contacts for certain data types with GRAPH

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get values for `PT_DOUBLE` and `PT_CLSID` custom property data types using Microsoft Graph.  I have no trouble getting custom properties for `PT_LONG` (Integer) or `PT_UNICODE` (String).  Integer and String does not work for `PT_DOUBLE` and `PT_CLSID` properties, and I get this error:

> ErrorInvalidExtendedProperty: The extended property attribute combination is invalid.

The [documentation on supported data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/extended-properties-rest-operations#ExtendedPropertyIdFormats.) is not very clear.

Here's a sample request that works for `PT_UNICODE` and `PT_LONG` props:

```http
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders/{id}/contacts?
 $top=1&
 $expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=
 (PropertyId eq  'String {1A417774-4779-47C1-9851-E42057495FCA} Name InlineLinks')+OR+
 (PropertyId eq  'String {1A417774-4779-47C1-9851-E42057495FCA} Name XrmCompanyPeople')+OR+
 (PropertyId eq 'Integer {1A417774-4779-47C1-9851-E42057495FCA} Name XrmContactType'))
```

I can live without `PT_DOUBLE`, but I really need to access these `PT_CLSID` props (`String` and `Guid` do not work):

```http
XrmContactId: Tag = 0x86680048; 
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{1A417774-4779-47C1-9851-E42057495FCA}/XrmContactId/0x00000048; 
Kind: MNID_STRING

XrmId: Tag = 0x86680048; 
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{1A417774-4779-47C1-9851-E42057495FCA}/XrmId/0x00000048; 
Kind: MNID_STRING
```

Does anyone know the data type name for `PT_CLSID` or list of supported data types for Microsoft Graph?  The [Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is painful to read through and it didn't give me any insights.

Comment: This list of allowed types as a string can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/exchangewebservices.mapipropertytypetype?view=exchange-ews-proxy

Answer (score 1):

For [SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#SingleValueLegacyExtendedPropertyResource_v2), both the PropertyID and Value elements are strings.

One bit of clarification, the API you're calling here is the [Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi) and not [Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs). While they provide similar functionality, they are distinct endpoints. [Extended Properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty) in Graph also only supports string values.

Comment: So to clarify: both APIs only support string extended properties? Note that I am able to get integer props. And as it turns out I don't need to access these props after all as EWS GetPersona + ItemLinkIds now gets me what I need