# Can't get SingleValueExtendedProperties from EXO Message with GRAPH

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, mapi

For reference, I read:

[Can't get SingleValueExtendedProperties from Outlook contacts for certain data types with GRAPH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691538/cant-get-singlevalueextendedproperties-from-outlook-contacts-for-certain-data-t)

Yes, I see that this thread is pretty old, but I hope you will still assist. So I was trying to execute a similar query:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/sentitems/messages/AAAB[truncated]BAAA=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%200x5D01001E')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/sentitems/messages/AAAB%5Btruncated%5DBAAA=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20%27String%200x5D01001E%27))

This is just POC at the moment as I was noticing the String Comments by Marc in the refered article. This particular property is

Tag: 0x5D01001E
Type: PT_STRING8
Property Name: PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS_A
Other Names: PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS, PidTagSenderSmtpAddress, PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS_W, ptagSenderSMTPAddress
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001E

I really would like the Binary property:

Tag: 0x00360003
Type: PT_LONG Property
Name: PR_SENSITIVITY  Other
Names: PidTagSensitivity,ptagSensitivity
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00360003

When trying either, the query runs without error, but I do not get the MAPI Property. I switched to the PTString8 property PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS to prove I can get a String, but Eric's post in the referred document seem to make me think he could get a Non String. Both queries run, but no MAPI Property.

Any help would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually see that property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage) or MFCMAPI on that particulate contact? I'd be surprised if sender properties like that were available on a contact.

Comment: It's not a contact. It is a MailItem, MessageClass IPM.Note.Yes, I see PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS and PR_SENSITIVITY in the MailItem, using MFCMapi. I used Outlook to Set Sensitivity to "Private" and PS_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS was of course already set as part of message creation.If you notice in the Graph URI you will see I am querying Messages from SentItems Folder. I get default Properties, however PR_SENSITIVITY not yet exposed in Graph, I am attempting to get it as well. Following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! (Also, note that my first example PR_SENDER_SMTP_ADDRESS 0x5D01, is undefined in Sentitems Folder).

*Please Note:
0x0036 = PR_SENSITIVITY

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{MessageID}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer 0x0036')

*Substitute the {MessageID} to be the Message Id of the Mail Message in question.